TypeError: n2 is not a function - mitt
When I am using mitt.emit() like this :
bus.emit('setData', data)
but it's wrong.
I don't know why.
What's more, when I use it in the other codes, it's OK.
enter image description hereenter image description here
How to fix this bug?
